# How to change the element's atrribute name of a given XML with Python

Tags: python, xml

This is the input XML file `input.xml`:

```
<edges>
  <edge from_="4" id_="488909c258004c9197c95f6f66bfec25" numLanes="3" to="0"/>
  <edge from_="1" id_="54e2c0a3f63b4e869fb6c62c0255ac9c" numLanes="3" to="0"/>
  <edge from_="3" id_="fc4d9a75d45343a4a2523c713f5e727c" numLanes="5" to="0"/>
  <edge from_="2" id_="2bf32d7d7b1545d58ea945a0c8a6e9a3" numLanes="3" to="0"/>
  <edge from_="0" id_="671fe5d822ba4093b2d5163708378f19" numLanes="3" to="4"/>
  <edge from_="0" id_="9ca39900ffe44887838f1f77edaedb90" numLanes="3" to="1"/>
  <edge from_="0" id_="d5435e6103b845a28b9a4c2ae1df2f02" numLanes="3" to="3"/>
  <edge from_="0" id_="2573a935d265469995d647fa5fe82599" numLanes="3" to="2"/>
</edges>
```

What I want to do is to change each `edge` element's attribute name `from_` to `from` and `id_` to `id`. So the output should like this:

```
<edges>
  <edge from="4" id="488909c258004c9197c95f6f66bfec25" numLanes="3" to="0"/>
  <edge from="1" id="54e2c0a3f63b4e869fb6c62c0255ac9c" numLanes="3" to="0"/>
  <edge from="3" id="fc4d9a75d45343a4a2523c713f5e727c" numLanes="5" to="0"/>
  <edge from="2" id="2bf32d7d7b1545d58ea945a0c8a6e9a3" numLanes="3" to="0"/>
  <edge from="0" id="671fe5d822ba4093b2d5163708378f19" numLanes="3" to="4"/>
  <edge from="0" id="9ca39900ffe44887838f1f77edaedb90" numLanes="3" to="1"/>
  <edge from="0" id="d5435e6103b845a28b9a4c2ae1df2f02" numLanes="3" to="3"/>
  <edge from="0" id="2573a935d265469995d647fa5fe82599" numLanes="3" to="2"/>
</edges>
```

I've tried to access the element's attribue via `xml.etree.ElementTree`, but don't know how to change it:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
with open('input.xml', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    tree = et.parse(f)
    root= tree.getroot()
    for edge in root:
        print(list(edge.attrib.keys())[:2])
```

How to do this with Python3?

Comment: Tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtin `xml` module for a simple thing like this. For example loading the data into an `ElementTree` using an ipython session:

```
In [35]: from xml.etree import ElementTree
In [36]: x = """
    ...: <edges>
    ...:   <edge from_="4" id_="488909c258004c9197c95f6f66bfec25" numLanes="3" to="0"/>
    ...:   <edge from_="1" id_="54e2c0a3f63b4e869fb6c62c0255ac9c" numLanes="3" to="0"/>
    ...:   <edge from_="3" id_="fc4d9a75d45343a4a2523c713f5e727c" numLanes="5" to="0"/>
    ...:   <edge from_="2" id_="2bf32d7d7b1545d58ea945a0c8a6e9a3" numLanes="3" to="0"/>
    ...:   <edge from_="0" id_="671fe5d822ba4093b2d5163708378f19" numLanes="3" to="4"/>
    ...:   <edge from_="0" id_="9ca39900ffe44887838f1f77edaedb90" numLanes="3" to="1"/>
    ...:   <edge from_="0" id_="d5435e6103b845a28b9a4c2ae1df2f02" numLanes="3" to="3"/>
    ...:   <edge from_="0" id_="2573a935d265469995d647fa5fe82599" numLanes="3" to="2"/>
    ...: </edges>
    ...: """


In [37]: elements = ElementTree.fromstring(x)
In [38]: for eachedge in elements:
    ...:     eachedge.attrib['id'] = eachedge.attrib['id_']
    ...:     eachedge.attrib['from'] = eachedge.attrib['from_']
    ...:     del eachedge.attrib['id_']
    ...:     del eachedge.attrib['from_']
    ...:
```

Result:

```
In [39]: print(etree.ElementTree.tostring(elements).decode())
<edges>
  <edge from="4" id="488909c258004c9197c95f6f66bfec25" numLanes="3" to="0" />
  <edge from="1" id="54e2c0a3f63b4e869fb6c62c0255ac9c" numLanes="3" to="0" />
  <edge from="3" id="fc4d9a75d45343a4a2523c713f5e727c" numLanes="5" to="0" />
  <edge from="2" id="2bf32d7d7b1545d58ea945a0c8a6e9a3" numLanes="3" to="0" />
  <edge from="0" id="671fe5d822ba4093b2d5163708378f19" numLanes="3" to="4" />
  <edge from="0" id="9ca39900ffe44887838f1f77edaedb90" numLanes="3" to="1" />
  <edge from="0" id="d5435e6103b845a28b9a4c2ae1df2f02" numLanes="3" to="3" />
  <edge from="0" id="2573a935d265469995d647fa5fe82599" numLanes="3" to="2" />
</edges>
```